# How do I serve a Polymer web app?

Tags: web-applications, server, polymer, polymer-1.0, backend

I want to deploy a [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) web app.

Since Polymer seems to manage routing with `<app-route>`, can I just install the [Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) on my server and run `polymer serve`? Or should I make a backend, and if so, how do I tie it to the Polymer frontend?

Comment: Thanks, @Queder. If you like my answer, i appreciate any Upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to install `polymer-cli` on your server.

Just follow the steps on https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#build.

So you should use `polymer build --entrypoint index.html` to build your application for production.
Afterwards in `/build/` folder you get two folders: `bundled` and `unbundled`.

Quoted from polymer-project.org:

> **bundled**. All fragments are bundled together to reduce the number of
> file requests. Optimal for sending to clients or serving from servers
> that are not HTTP/2 compatible.
>
> **unbundled**. Fragments are unbundled.
> Optimal for HTTP/2-compatible servers and clients.

Just upload the contents of one of them to your server and your application will be served.

Answer (score 1):

`polymer-cli` is great for generating apps hosted under the root path `/`, but not under any subroot like `app/` or `shop-app/`, because is uses absolute paths in its build process. `<app-route>` seems to be the right way to go, but configuring it via `polymer-cli` is not yet supported. The idea is to use a separate server for every app running under the root path. See related Stackoverflow Post [Serving Polymer App to a /path not at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090070/serving-polymer-app-to-a-path-not-at-root) and Polymer Blog Post [Encapsulated Routing with Elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing): An overview to doing distributed routing in an application, as well as an introduction to `<app-route>` and `<app-location>`