# Serving Polymer App to a /path not at root

Tags: polymer

So the first thing I want to do with a new Polymer app is deploy to a directory on an existing website. The only thing that seems to work is deploying to root `/`.

Let's take the Shop example. I do:

1. `polymer init` and choose shop
2. `polymer build`
3. `Robocopy.exe .\build\bundled\ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\p\ /MIR`
4. `start http://localhost/p/`

You see I'm on Windows. I assume that using IIS is irrelevant, since I'm relying on the server just to serve static content.

**What do I need to edit in the shop template to make it work at the url `http://localhost/p/`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polymer-cli created apps came with assumption of serving from root level '/'. In generated project `index.html` you will find two comments

```html
<!--

      The `<base>` tag below is present to support two advanced deployment options:
      1) Differential serving. 2) Serving from a non-root path.
    
      Instead of manually editing the `<base>` tag yourself, you should generally either:
      a) Add a `basePath` property to the build configuration in your `polymer.json`.
      b) Use the `--base-path` command-line option for `polymer build`.
    
      Note: If you intend to serve from a non-root path, see [polymer-root-path] below.

-->
    <base href="/">
<!-- ... -->

<script>
    /**
    * [polymer-root-path]
    *
    * By default, we set `Polymer.rootPath` to the server root path (`/`).
    * Leave this line unchanged if you intend to serve your app from the root
    * path (e.g., with URLs like `my.domain/` and `my.domain/view1`).
    *
    * If you intend to serve your app from a non-root path (e.g., with URLs
    * like `my.domain/my-app/` and `my.domain/my-app/view1`), edit this line
    * to indicate the path from which you'll be serving, including leading
    * and trailing slashes (e.g., `/my-app/`).
    */
    window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/'};
  // ...    
 

</script>
```

if in this `index.html` file you comment out `base` tag and set window.Polymer `rootPath` to something like `'/0/polymer-test/build/es5-bundled/'` you will be able to navigate in app on `http://localhost/0/polymer-test/build/es5-bundled/`

Comment: `--base-path` command-line option for `polymer build` is not available.

Comment: Update. Polymer 3 CLI does update <base href>. 
`polymer build --preset es6-bundled --base-path "/CompetitiveApp/build/es6-bundled/" `
In order to be used the global config JS object need to be set accordingly. The unified way is
<!-- language: lang-js -->
     window.MyAppGlobals = { rootPath: document.querySelector('base').getAttribute('href') };

Comment: Sasha, your solutions worked partially in my case. Polymer app runs at my origin/context application, but the styles included in custom component template: `<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href= "/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-blue.css">` can not be loaded. I've tried without succes with relative path to node_modules. In standalone polymer 3 application everything works fine.

Comment: @Tihomir, have you checked the css is presented in bundle? It could be the dependency in link tag is not checked and build bundle is missing it. In that case you want to add css into *extraDependencies* section of polymer.json

Comment: Meanwhile I've posted a question about this subject, I found it too extensive subject to be discussed in comments; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617999/external-style-file-not-loaded-in-polymer-3-application-deployed-to-spring-mvc-a

Answer (score 3):

The Polymer `shop-app` assumes it will be deployed on the server root. Therefore it has all of the links and routes hard-coded to that assumption.

This means, that you will have to change all of the following:

- all absolute links between the pages,
- all `pattern` parameters in `app-route` elements (this is not necessary when `useHashAsPath = true`),
- all absolute imports, including the lazy ones via `importHref`,
- update the absolute locations within the service worker (use instructions from [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/256#issuecomment-254556067)) and
- all references to static content (CSS, images, JS files)

---

I'm guessing your main goal isn't porting the `shop-app`, but rather future proofing your own app so that it can also be deployed to non-root locations on the server.

For this, I will mention two ways, depending on which value of `useHashAsPath` you use for the `app-location` element. This setting defaults to `false`, which means that you must use full URLs, instead of the *hashbang* equivalents.

**Scenario 1**: `useHashAsPath = true`

This is the easiest of both approaches, since you simply treat all URLs between the pages as *absolute* links. For example: `<a href="#/tabs/">Tabs</a>`.

The next step is to reference all static content and imports via relative links.

The last step is to update your service worker as shown [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/256#issuecomment-254556067).

**Scenario 2**: `useHashAsPath = false`

If you dislike the *hashbang* URLs, go for this scenario. As you can figure out, this approach is a bit more difficult, but still manageable (especially when you start from scratch).

Firstly, you *should* still use absolute links, since relative links between a complex routing scheme can quickly cause problems (e.g. when not all pages are on the same directory level).

But since absolute links are a no-go, you will have to add some additional pre-processing upon build time. The point is to prefix all links with, say `__ROOT__`, and then replace all of those values with your actual document root. The links would then look like something this:

```
<a href="__ROOT__/some/page">Some page</a>
```

And you would use `gulp-replace` or something similar to replace `__ROOT_` with `/your-document-root` across all of your source files in order to produce something like this:

```
<a href="/your-document-root/some/page">Some page</a>
```

At this point, you've got your links fixed. But this is only part of the problem. You must also apply the same *fix* to all of your `app-route` elements. For example:

```
<app-route pattern="__ROOT__/some/page" [...]></app-route> // Other parameters ommited
```

As with other resources, such as images and CSS files, you can also include them as absolute links and add the `__ROOT__` prefix, but I would advise against this and would rather use relative paths.

The last step is to update your service worker as shown [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/256#issuecomment-254556067).

---

Read more about routing: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing