# How to set base URL for Polymer app

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I want to configure my Polymer app to launch at this URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/polymer
```

Instead of the default:

```
http://localhost:8081
```

How do I set the base URL for the app?

I tried the following but couldn't seem to get it to work:

**package.json**

```
{
    "homepage": "http://localhost:8081/polymer"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Polymer.rootPath` and `Polymer.importPath`.  https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#urls-in-templates Somewhere in your app shell you should define `Polymer.rootPath = 'somePath'` (however you want to conjure it up), then elsewhere in your app if you need to utilize that path you use it like this:

```
<iron-ajax url="[[rootPath]]api/somepath/somepath"></iron-ajax>
```

Comment: a bit different explanation on how-to is on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090070/serving-polymer-app-to-a-path-not-at-root/46310630#46310630