# How to Keep app-route in Sync with Page View When Using base href URL (Polymer)

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am using Polymer `shop-app` and trying to deploy at `domain/app`.  I set `<base href="domain/app/"`, which loads the app shell properly, but fails to load the page views.

Is there a way to set the `base href` in the `app-route` component, or is there another method to fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the whatever route you are deploying your app to in the setup of `app-route` element, e.g.:

```
<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="domain/app/:page"
  ...
```

And according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090070/serving-polymer-app-to-a-path-not-at-root) you need to fix all static links hardcoded in the shop app template.