# How to deploy a polymer 3.0 build on NGINX (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, polymer

How can I configure the Polymer build so I can deploy my app built on Windows to my Raspberry Pi running NGINX (in a sub directory)?

I could not install `polymer-cli` directly on my Raspberry Pi since the `chromedriver` (which `polymer-cli` needs) is only available for 64 bit Linux and the official Raspian OS is currently 32 bit only.

So I installed polymer-cli on my Windows machine, and created my first Polymer app according to https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/set-up, I also created the new-view page.

I can now run the app using `polymer serve` (which shows the app correctly in the browser on the Windows machine) and build using `polymer build`. Now I want to deploy so I copied the `build` directory (which contains three built variants, `es5-bundled`, `es6-bundled` and `esm-bundled`) to a sub-directory of the NGINX root, `/var/www/html/polymer/build`.

Firing up my browser and pointing at `http://<raspberrypi-ip>/polymer/build/esm-build` I see two errors.

The `src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"` and `src="src/my-app.js"` in `index.html` gives 404. I could not find how to configure polymer-cli to change these, and still serve a working app in Windows so I manually added `polymer/default/` to those two paths in the `index.html`.

Now I end up with a grey page in my browser, no further error messages...

Moving to my phones browser and entering the same url, `http://<raspberrypi-ip>/polymer/esm-build`, I actually see my app, together with an `Oops you hit a 404. Head back to home` link. following that link I get to my app, which seems to be working - but the URL is now `http://<raspberrypi-ip>/new-view`.

I've also played with the NGINX `try_files`without luck...

```
server {
...
location /polymer/default {
   try_files $uri /polymer/default/index.html =404;
   }
}
```

EDIT: In [Serving Polymer App to a /path not at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090070/serving-polymer-app-to-a-path-not-at-root/46310630#46310630) I found out that I also need to adjust `rootPath` in index.html. However I still get the 404 described above if I point my browser at `http://<raspberrypi-ip>/polymer/esm-build/index.html`...

Also, is there any way to refer to the `rootPath` in the `<script src="">`tag I manually edited above?

This is my first encounter with Polymer and NGINX, so any pointers are appreciated.