# Build polymer app for non root path

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I think this is not a duplicate of [Serving Polymer App to a /path not at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090070/serving-polymer-app-to-a-path-not-at-root), because it is about newer versions of Polymer-cli version 1.8 and Polymer 3

I have created a very simple component that works with "polymer serve" and with "polymer build" when served from the root path.

According to the documentation, you can build the application for non-root paths, using the --base-path build option. However, this does not seem to work for all resources

Example project is on github https://github.com/anneb/polymer-simple-component/

The basics:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Polymer app</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>    
    <script type="module" src="src/components/simple-component.js"></script>
    <simple-component></simple-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

The simple-component with relative reference to ../../images/spinner.gif:

```
import {LitElement, html} from '@polymer/lit-element';
class SimpleComponent extends LitElement {
  _render() {
    return html`<div><img src="../../images/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner"></div>`;
  }
}
customElements.define('simple-component', SimpleComponent);
```

The above works (spinner visible) if tested with

```
polymer serve
```

and

```
polymer build
```

However, when built with:

```
polymer build --name es5-bundled --base-path es5-bundled
```

You can now serve es5-bundled from the build directory (parent of build/es5-bundled) and the code now mostly uses path /es5-bundled/, but the referenced spinner.gif is still expected at /images/spinner.gif, why?

My polymer.json:

```
{
    "entrypoint": "index.html",
    "shell": "src/components/simple-component.js",
    "sources": [
      "images/**/*"
    ],
    "extraDependencies": [
      "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**"
    ],
    "builds": [
      {
        "name": "es5-bundled",
        "js": {
          "compile": "es5",
          "minify": true,
          "transformModulesToAmd": true
        },
        "css": {
          "minify": true
        },
        "html": {
          "minify": true
        },
        "bundle": true,
        "addServiceWorker": true
      }
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "npm": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example component is using a relative path:

```
return html`<div><img src="../../images/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner"></div>`;
```

This might be improved using the module URL from `import.meta.url` as follows:

```
return html`<div>
  <img src$="${new URL('../../images/spinner.gif', import.meta.url).href}" alt="Spinner">
  </div>`;
```

As `import.meta.url` is not supported by for example Firefox, you have to `polymer build` using option [--js-transform-import-meta](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli-commands#meta):

```
polymer build --name es5-bundled --build-path es5-bundled --js-transform-import-meta
```

Another workaround for `import.meta.url` that will work for single page apps is:

```
return html`<div>
  <img src$="${this.baseURI}/images/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner">
  </div>`;
```

Comment: I had the same problem with loading stylesheet resource in app served from non-root location. Following works:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href$="[[this.base_uri]]node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" >`